# Swift: "Where" vs "If"

Tags: swift, if-statement, where-clause

Is there any difference between these two syntaxes? If not, any benefit?

```
if let userName = userNameTextField.text where userName.characters.count > 0,
        let password = passwordTextField.text where password.characters.count > 0,
        let confirmation = confirmationTextField.text where confirmation == password
    else {
        return false
    }
```

and:

```
if userNameTextField.text?.characters.count > 0 &&
        passwordTextField.text?.characters.count > 0 &&
    confirmationTextField.text == passwordTextField.text
    {
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, note that `where` clauses in optional binding conditions is deprecated in Swift 3.0, replaced by `,`.

- [Evolution Proposal SE-0099: Restructuring Condition Clauses](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md)

I.e.

```
let opt: Int?

/* Swift < 3 */
if let opt = opt where opt == 42 { /* ... */ }

/* Swift >= 3 */
if let opt = opt, opt == 42 { /* ... */ }
```

Secondly, your second example block wont compile in Swift >= 3.0, as the *optional* result from the optional chaining is not unwrapped; comparing optionals to literals has been removed in Swift 3.0 (thanks @MartinR), as per the following implemented proposals:

- [Evolution proposal SE-0121: Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md)
- [Evolution proposal SE-0123: Disallow coercion to optionals in operator arguments](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0123-disallow-value-to-optional-coercion-in-operator-arguments.md)

> ```
> userNameTextField.text?.characters.count > 0 &&
> /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>    this is an optional that, for Swift >= 3.0, needs to be unwrapped 
>    prior to comparing it to the integer literal */
> ```

---

Now, proceeding to answer your *"is there any difference ..."* question, assuming we look at your two options fixed for Swift 3.

- You could choose to bind the value of the optional `String` property `text` of `userNameTextField` *if you'd like to use it in the if block that follows*, or
- If youd only want to ascertain that the `text` property is not `nil` or empty (`""`), you could omit the binding in favour or simply checking its `character.count`

E.g.:

```
struct Foo {
    var bar: String?
}
var foo = Foo()

/* if you want to use foo.bar within the if block */
if let str = foo.bar, str.characters.count > 0 {
    // do something with str ...
    print(str)
}

/* if you only need to ascertain foo.bar is not nil
   and not empty */
if (foo.bar?.characters.count ?? 0) > 0 {
    // do something with str ...
    print("not empty")
}

// alternatively ... (not nil or empty)
if !(foo.bar?.isEmpty ?? true) {
    // do something with str ...
    print("not empty")
}
```

If you simply want to ascertain the latter and return `false` in case the ascertation fails, you could prefer using a `guard` statement instead of `if`:

```
guard (foo.bar?.characters.count ?? 0) > 0 else { return false }
// ... if no false return, proceed with app flow here ...

// alternatively ...
guard !(foo.bar?.isEmpty ?? true) else { return false }
```

Comment: The second example *does* compile in Swift 2 (unless I am mistaken). The feature to compare optionals has been removed in Swift 3.

Comment: @MartinR Ah , I didn't know that was ever possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Neither version works in Swift 3. And I think in the first version, you meant to use `guard` instead of `let`.

With Swift 3, you want to do the following:

```
guard
  let userName = userNameTextField.text,
  let password = passwordTextField.text,
  let confirmation = confirmationTextField.text,
  userName.characters.count > 0,
  password.characters.count > 0,
  confirmation == password
else {
  return false
}
```

Comment: You *can* compare optionals with `>` in Swift 2.

Comment: Yep thanks - saw your other comment. Was news to me!

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with using your approach in Swift 3 as explained by some of the other answers. But if you are using Swift 2, the following is my answer to your question.

The two are exactly the same with only one difference. Both approaches are testing for a nil value and then introducing a boolean test if the value is not nil. For example in your line,

```
    if let userName = userNameTextField.text where userName.characters.count > 0
```

You are testing to see if userNameTextField is not nil and then you are testing if its count is greater than zero. The same thing applies this line,

```
    if userNameTextField.text?.characters.count > 0
```

except it is much shorter and readable.

Because both approaches are within an 'if' statement, they both evaluate to true or false and achieve the same purpose.

However, what separates them is that with the 'where' clause, you can introduce a Boolean test after a binding or pattern, regardless of whether or not there's an underlying semantic link between the two. So I can basically do this with the 'where' clause,

```
    if let userName = userNameTextField.text where age > 0
```

There is no semantic link between userNameTextField and age. As you can imagine, that might not be what you intended and this can quickly lead to errors.